If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then $Z$ defined by $Z(\omega,\eta)=X(\omega)+Y(\eta)$ has the same distribution as $X+Y$.
Let $1\leqq p<\infty$, $E$ be a Banach space and $X,Y:\Omega\to E$ are independent random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, P)$ with $X,Y\in L^p$. And define $Z:\Omega\times\Omega\to E$ by $Z(\omega,\eta):=X(\omega)+Y(\eta)$. Then, why does $Z$ have the same distribution as $X+Y$ ?
My book says this is immediate from the independence of $X$ and $Y$, but I don't understand why.
I have to see $P(Z\in B)=P(X+Y\in B)$ for any Borel set $B\in\mathbb B(E)$. Now, I have $$P(Z\in B)=\{(\omega,\eta)\in \Omega^2\mid X(\omega)+Y(\eta)\in B\}$$ and $$P(X+Y\in B)=\{\omega\in \Omega\mid X(\omega)+Y(\omega)\in B\}.$$ And by the independence of $X$ and $Y$, I have $$P(X\in B_1, Y\in B_2)=P(X\in B_1)P(Y\in B_2)$$ for any Borel sets $B_1$ and $B_2$.
Conbining these facts, how can I see $P(Z\in B)=P(X+Y\in B)$ ?

You did not specify the distribution and $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega\times\Omega$, but if the first one is the product of $P$ and the second is the product $\sigma$-algebra, then $X'(\omega, \eta)=X(\omega)$ and $Y'(\omega,\eta)=Y(\eta)$ are clearly independent and have the same distribution marginal as the original $X$ and $Y$, therefore $Z'=X'+Y'$ have the same distribution as $Z=X+Y$.
